# Desktop items not always keeping position on boot

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I use my desktop like a real desktop and keep a small number of items on it that I'm currently working on arranged in a manner that makes sense to me so I can find what I want.

Sometimes, after a reboot, the files and folder don't retain thier postions, and end up sorted up the left edge. This often happens to *only* newly added icons (with many older files quite happily sat in their previous positions).

I assume that somehow the desktop "state" isn't being saved correctly?

Does anyone know what might be causing this to happen, and how/where the desktop state is saved?

Comment: This happens on XP too :(

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer to stuff moving around at random (which shouldn't happen), but [fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) from stardock is a pretty useful tool for keeping a desktop organised - and it seems to do a good job at remembering positions. Its one of those things i wish was default on windows.

Comment: Looks interesting, but stuff tends to stay on my desktop for pretty short periods (my recycle bin lives on the taskbar, so my DT is *entirely* "current" objects) - so, while this might work around this issue, I'm not sure installing it would be worth while for me - but that's for the suggestion.

Comment: Fences kicks a lot of tail. I *believe* SmartMon (Sorry, not in front of my PC at the moment) also has a 'preserve desktop layout' function.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to this problem on Windows Server 2008, I tried [this program](http://www.intowindows.com/save-and-restore-desktop-icon-positions-layout-from-context-menu/) to save and restore the layout. It seems to work well. Actually fixing the Windows behavior would obviously be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The two reasons I know for moving random icons on the Windows desktop are:
either a change of the resolution: changing to a smaller resolution rearranges the 'cut-off' icons.
Or like you already stated: an unsaved state of the desktop. Even if icons or other files are saved once and their location has been saved by windows, a change of these files (like changing your python-code and then saving it) might rearrange them if the desktop-state wasn't saved at shut-down.

Comment: Ok, well I can rule out resolution changes in my case. So, what might cause the desktop state to not be saved? My system is shutdown correctly after use.

Comment: Windows 95 had a feature that allowed you to save your settings without shutting down.  If I remember correctly, you would follow the normal procedure for shutting down, but hold the Shift key down, and it would save your settings but not shut down.  Sadly, I don't think this feature was carried over to later version of Windows.